# Angular $http useCredentials return error

Tags: angularjs, drupal, angularjs-http, drupal-services, angularjs-authentication

I am trying to build an AngularJS frontend for a Drupal 7 website.

The problem is that, when I set `useCredentails` to `true`, I get this error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

I have the following headers set on the backend:

> - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> - Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
> - Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type, Cookie, X-CSRF-Token
> - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

The login works fine with `useCredentails` equals `false`. When changed to true, I get the above error.

I wanna be able to set `useCredentails` to `true`, in order to be able to use token authentication.

Any ideas?

P.S. I use drupal 7 services module with session autehntication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in CORS configuration on the server.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` can not be set to `*` while `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is set to `true`.

I changed `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to specific hosts, and everything worked fine.